# Iframe is not loading due to CSP

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, content-security-policy, twitch

I have this twitch iframe on my website

```
<iframe id="rindle-frame" scrolling="no" width="100%" allowfullscreen="" height="100%" allow="autoplay" src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=rocket_league_s&amp;parent=casinomhub-sportsbook-staging.gtdevteam.xyz&amp;parent=stage.casinomhub.com&amp;muted=true&amp;&amp;autoplay=true&amp;mute=true"></iframe>
```

Webpage URL is https://stage.casinomhub.com/tr/sportsbook?page=/event/2361318349402673181?isLive=true

I see this result.

[image]

Error logged is: Refused to frame 'https://player.twitch.tv/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://casinomhub-sportsbook-staging.gtdevteam.xyz https://stage.casinomhub.com".

Thanks in advance

Comment: The fact that your iframe URL contains _two_ `parent` parameters, looks a bit suspicious - is it supposed to be like that?